# Pass a string to php and then pass it back to Powershell

Tags: php, powershell, variables

I have a Powershell variable that is a randomly generated password which I then want to pass on to a PHP script. In my PHP script the generated password is processed (Hash) and then I need to pass it back to Powershell.

How to do that?

Below is the actual code.
Is their a way to get all in Powershell?
Most of my code is copy and pasted and I do not understand everything.

```
return shell_exec($unsanitized);
}

function PowerShellFile($File)
{
$unsanitized = sprintf('powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%s"', $File);

return shell_exec($unsanitized);
}


define("PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM", "sha256");
define("PBKDF2_ITERATIONS", 1000);
define("PBKDF2_SALT_BYTE_SIZE", 24);
define("PBKDF2_HASH_BYTE_SIZE", 24);
define("HASH_SECTIONS", 4);
define("HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX", 0);
define("HASH_ITERATION_INDEX", 1);
define("HASH_SALT_INDEX", 2);
define("HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX", 3);
define("USE_OPENSSL_RANDOM", false);
function pbkdf2_create_hash($password)
{
    // format: algorithm:iterations:salt:hash
    $salt = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(PBKDF2_SALT_BYTE_SIZE, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
    return PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM . ":" . PBKDF2_ITERATIONS . ":" .  $salt . ":" .
    base64_encode(pbkdf2_apply(
        PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM,
        $password,
        $salt,
        PBKDF2_ITERATIONS,
        PBKDF2_HASH_BYTE_SIZE,
        true
    ));
}
    function pbkdf2_apply($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false)
{
    $algorithm = strtolower($algorithm);
    if(!in_array($algorithm, hash_algos(), true))
    die('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid hash algorithm.');
    if($count <= 0 || $key_length <= 0)
    die('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid parameters.');
    $hash_length = strlen(hash($algorithm, "", true));
    $block_count = ceil($key_length / $hash_length);
    $output = "";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $block_count; $i++) {

        $last = $salt . pack("N", $i);

        $last = $xorsum = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true);

        for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
            $xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
        }
    $output .= $xorsum;
    }
    if($raw_output)
        return substr($output, 0, $key_length);
    else
        return bin2hex(substr($output, 0, $key_length));
}

(array)$userr = file("test.txt");
foreach($userr AS $user)
{





 echo "\n";


/**********************************************************************/



$password =PowerShellCommand("C:\Users\Pydio\Desktop\zufall.ps1");

$hash = pbkdf2_create_hash($password);
echo $hash;
```

}

Comment: Thx for making my Grammar good. My english is so bad :>

Comment: Is the PHP script using a standard encryption mechanism?. What do have sofar? Is there already a proto PHP script? If the encryption process in PHP is indeed standard, why not doing everything in PowerShell?

Comment: Well Good question
The thing is i cant programm very well and i dont find the functions for Powershell that i have in php.

Comment: I recommend you to add what you currently have in PHP to your question. It will probably make your request a lot easier to understand.

Comment: Give me a secound

Comment: Stackoverflow didnt shows my code correcly he is not formattet

Comment: so that is what i need in powershell